# Installing cleardb on a local Cloud Foundry installation

Tags: vagrant, cloud-foundry, cleardb

I am new to Cloud Foundry and I want to set up a local CF instance in Vagrant. I followed the steps described in http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/boshlite/ and got a local instance up and running. I am also able to deploy a simple Ruby app into CF.

Now I want to deploy the Spring sample application from https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/gsg-spring.html into CF for which I need a ClearDB database service.

Using the command proposed to create a service instance `cf create-service cleardb spark mysql` I get the following error:

```
Creating service instance mysql in org test-org / space test-space as admin...
FAILED
Service offering cleardb not found
```

When I check my service marketplace in my CF installation with `cf marketplace` I get

```
Getting services from marketplace in org test-org / space test-space as admin...
OK

No service offerings found
```

This brings me to the suggestion that there are "no services installed". So my question is: how can I install a clearDB service in a local CF environment - and is this possible at all, since the Github projects says something like

> Prior to deployment, the operator should define three subnets via their infrastructure provider. The MySQL release is designed to be deployed across three subnets to ensure availability in the event of a subnet failure. During installation, a fourth subnet is required for compilation vms.

Any help / resource is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Foundry as a Pivotal-sponsored open source project predates Cloud Foundry as its own independent open source project, so what you're seeing is actually shared documentation that still has some references specific to Pivotal Web Services: http://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/java/gsg-spring.html.  I'd encourage you to raise the issue against the buildpacks documentation repo (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/docs-buildpacks/issues), you can reference this search result: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/docs-buildpacks/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cleardb

All it means is you need a MySQL database service.  Hosted Cloud Foundry offerings often have ready-to-go MySQL service offerings (such as ClearDB) in their marketplaces; if you're deploying your own Cloud Foundry then you have a couple options.

1. Provision a MySQL database externally (not as part of your BOSH-Lite), and bind it to your application as a "user-provided service": https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html
2. Deploy your own MySQL service to BOSH-Lite and register a service broker.  Here's a release that's ready to use, with instructions for deploying: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release

Comment: Hi Amit! Funny enough my pair and I ran into the same issue 20 minutes after you responded. We followed all the steps described in the cf-mysql doc and also found the magical `cups` command and got the service added. However, we are trying to deploy the sample Spring pong app and are getting connection errors from JDBC. Any idea if there is another step not in the docs that we need to take? I assumed the configuration of network etc. would be handled by CF.